# Minifiers not merging selectors of same rules

Tags: css, sass, minify

I'm using `sass` to customize Bootstrap. But when analyzing the minified output, I see that there were two of `body {}` selectors.

Here is my compile command:

```bash
sass --load-path=./scss --style=compressed --no-source-map scss/bootstrap.scss ../../public_html/css/bootstrap.css
```

Not satisfied, I did a test several css minifiers in the internet in order to get the best minification. Here is the test input:

```css
body{
    margin:0;
}

body {
    margin-top:60px;
}
```

Great part of websites returned this minification (which the same result returned by sass):

```css
body{margin:0}body{margin-top:60px}
```

Which is not what I intended.

But one [specific website](https://www.toptal.com/developers/cssminifier) returned this minification:

```css
body{margin:60px 0 0}
```

---

Which library can grant me this incredible power of minification (Aka merging selectors of same rules)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[csso](https://github.com/css/csso) merges repeated selectors.

Give it a try in this live minifier:

https://css.github.io/csso/csso.html

Comment: Wonderful! That's the exact thing I needed!